# Tax Brackets and Volume Discounts using Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, discount, tax, excel-lambda

It's the end of January and that magical feeling of "tax time" is starting up around the world. A common problem is to calculate tax owed based on a set of tax brackets and rates. This is also similar to calculating total order costs based on a quantity and volume discounted prices.

I've seen some old questions/answers based on this problem type, but none are treating it as a general function, so I thought I would post one here. The idea is to create a general solution using `LET` which can be wrapped into `LAMBDA` when that is available.

### US Federal Income Tax Rates 2021

So, let's start with the 2021 US Federal Income Tax Tables as an example:

| Tax rate | Single From | Single To | Head of household From | Head of household To | Married filing jointly From | Married filing jointly To | Married filing separately From | Married filing separately To |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10% | - | 9,950 | - | 14,200 | - | 19,900 | - | 9,950 |
| 12% | 9,951 | 40,525 | 14,201 | 54,200 | 19,901 | 81,050 | 9,951 | 40,525 |
| 22% | 40,526 | 86,375 | 54,201 | 86,350 | 81,051 | 172,750 | 40,526 | 86,375 |
| 24% | 86,376 | 164,925 | 86,351 | 164,900 | 172,751 | 329,850 | 86,376 | 164,925 |
| 32% | 164,926 | 209,425 | 164,901 | 209,400 | 329,851 | 418,850 | 164,926 | 209,425 |
| 35% | 209,426 | 523,600 | 209,401 | 523,600 | 418,851 | 628,300 | 209,426 | 314,150 |
| 37% | 523,600 |  | 523,600 |  | 628,300 |  | 314,151 |  |

So the question is - **what is the total tax owed for a given taxable income?**  For example, 100k. *(The correct answer is 18021)*

### Volume Discount Pricing

Let's also take another example of the same family - volume discounted pricing. Here is a table showing order quantity and unit prices for each tranche of order quantity.

| Qty From | Qty To | Unit Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 16.00 |
| 101 | 250 | 14.40 |
| 251 | 500 | 12.96 |
| 501 | 1000 | 11.66 |
| 1001 | 2000 | 10.49 |
| 2001 | 5000 | 9.44 |
| 5001 | 10000 | 8.50 |

A question might be: **what would an order of 1200 units cost?** *(The correct answer is 14928)*

### How the Calculation Works

Both the tax table and volume discounting calculate by accumulating across the brackets at each tax rate or discounted unit price.

**Example - tax calc**
A Single Person with taxable income of 50,000 would have taxes of:

```
9950 * 10% +

(40525-9950) * 12% +

(50000-40525) * 22% = 6748.50
```

**Example - volume discounting**
An order of 220 units would pay 16 per unit for the first 100 and and 14.40 per unit of the next 120:

```
100 * 16.00 +

(220-100) * 14.40 = 3328
```

### Objective

Have a formula that can be used for general purpose volume discounting or tax table calculation.

I will post my own solution, but I will not mark is as the answer - I'm sure there are better solutions out there and perhaps someone with `LAMBDA` can show how this can be built as a general solution.

### Related Questions

[IF statement to return different values for 3+ conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741560/if-statement-to-return-different-values-for-3-conditions)

[Complicated formula required to work out costs including multiple discounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942719/complicated-formula-required-to-work-out-costs-including-multiple-discounts)

[Array formula basics instead of nested if-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414760/array-formula-basics-instead-of-nested-if-else)

[Using Excel is it possible to plot a graph without explicitly generating table data, but using only a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66628760/using-excel-is-it-possible-to-plot-a-graph-without-explicitly-generating-table-d)

Comment: Please show the work you've done so far to solve this problem so we can help you through the issues you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

> I had to change this because I realized after looking at Solar Mike's
> reply that I was miscalculating the bracket sizes.

So here is my approach. With Office 365, I would use a LET as follows:

```
=LET( a, $K2,
        from, tTax2021[Single From],
        to, tTax2021[Single To],
        m, tTax2021[Tax rate],

        t, IF( ISBLANK( to ), a, to ),
        i, SEQUENCE( ROWS(t),,0 ),
        f, IF( i = 0, 0, INDEX( t, i ) ),
        bracketIdx, MATCH( a, from, 1 ),
        bracketSize, t-f,
        mb, m*bracketSize,
        rmb, LET( array, mb,
                   rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS( array ) ),
                   ones, --(rSeq >= TRANSPOSE( rSeq )),
                   MMULT( ones, array ) ),
       cumBase, INDEX( rmb, MAX(1,bracketIdx-1) ) * SIGN( bracketIdx-1 ),
       prorataBracket, ( a - INDEX( f, bracketIdx ) ) / INDEX( bracketSize, bracketIdx ) * INDEX( mb, bracketIdx ),
       cumBase + prorataBracket )
```

Where:

**a** is the amount that I put in cell K2. In the tax example, it would be 100000.

**f** is the from column that defines the brackets.

**t** is the to column that defines the brackets.

**m** is the marginal rate for each bracket.

### Tax Table Case

Here is a view of it deployed with an Excel Table called tTax2021.

[image]

### Volume Discount Case

Here is the same formula applied to the Volume Discount problem above:

[image]

### Simplified Table

Some tax and discounting tables have only a **From** column and no **To** column. In reality, the To column is superfluous in any case, so here is a version that only accepts the From column:

```
=LET( a, $K2,
        from, tTax2021[Single From],
        m, tTax2021[Tax rate],

        i, SEQUENCE( ROWS(from),,0 ),
        to, IFERROR( INDEX( from, i+2 ), a+1 ),
        bracketSize, to-from,
        bracketIdx, MATCH( a, from, 1 ),
        mb, m*bracketSize,
        rmb, LET( array, mb,
                   rSeq, SEQUENCE( ROWS( array ) ),
                   ones, --(rSeq >= TRANSPOSE( rSeq )),
                   MMULT( ones, array ) ),
       cumBase, INDEX( rmb, MAX(1,bracketIdx-1) ) * SIGN( bracketIdx-1 ),
       prorataBracket, ( a - INDEX( from, bracketIdx ) ) / INDEX( bracketSize, bracketIdx ) * INDEX( mb, bracketIdx ),
       cumBase + prorataBracket )
```

### LAMBDA Function

OK - so I finally have access to LAMBDA which allows this to be a more generalized function. So here is a LAMBDA version based on the simplified table above:

```
// Applies degressive pricing, volume discounting, or progressive taxation to 
//  a given Amount based on marginal units (or rates) for each Bracket.
//  amount : the sales order or income amount [value, array or range]
//  fromBrackets : the minumum amount for each bracket [array or range]
//  marginalUnits : the unit price or the tax rate within each bracket [array or range sized the same as fromBrackets]
BRACKETSUM =
LAMBDA( amount, fromBrackets, marginalUnits,

     LET(
            i, SEQUENCE( ROWS(fromBrackets),,0 ),
            to, IFERROR( INDEX( fromBrackets, i+2 ), a+1 ),
            bracketSize, to-fromBrackets,
            bracketIdx, MATCH( amount, fromBrackets, 1 ),
            mb, marginalUnits*bracketSize,
            rmb, SCAN(0,mb,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)),
           cumBase, INDEX( rmb, MAX(1,bracketIdx-1) ) * SIGN( bracketIdx-1 ),
           prorataBracket, ( amount - INDEX( fromBrackets, bracketIdx ) ) / INDEX( bracketSize, bracketIdx ) * INDEX( mb, bracketIdx ),
           cumBase + prorataBracket )
)
```

Comment: hmmm - looking at the answer from Solar Mike made me realize that my answer is flawed. the **bracketSize** is not t-f. It has to be t - previous t. So mine will have to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with the simple vlookup as so:

```
=VLOOKUP(E2,A2:C8,3,1)*E2
```

[image]

I get 11329.26 using:

```
(((VLOOKUP(E2,$A$2:$C$8,3,1)-VLOOKUP(E2+1000,$A$2:$C$8,3,1))/1000*E2)+VLOOKUP(E2+1000,$A$2:$C$8,3,1)*E2)
```

Comment: Hey - That does not quite get it. The answer should be 14928. The first 100 cost 16, the next 150 cost 14.40, etc. I am just realizing a flaw in my formula as well. I forgot to subtract out the difference between the tranches, so I will need to repair it.

Comment: So, if you need to do interpolation, then you can use vlookup muiltiple times to get the upper and lower quantity values and their difference and the two corresponding unit values and thwewir difference. Then all you have to calculate is the cost amount based on the amount of quantity above the lower value which gives the ratio then add that to the lower cost. A nice problem which will be a good exercise. (done way back when I analysed engine test results for my final year project and I was emulating a Mac which had Excel and Word on an Atari...)

Comment: Dated yourself... and me too. X-D

Comment: By hand calc, a qty of 1200 gets `100*16 +150*14.4 + 250*12.96 + 500*11.66 + 200*10.49`. This comes to 14928. A more clear example might be tax tables because it's how tax tables work in general, but volume discount pricing has the same mechanism. Thanks to your answer, I spotted a bug in mine. I don't think the IRS would appreciate it. ;-)

Comment: So you assume cumulative amounts to get the quantity… that takes a different approach - perhaps sumproduct()

Comment: Exactly - that's how tax tables work. You accumulate taxes within each bracket which is the same principle for volume discounting. I hadn't thought of SUMPRODUCT. The columnwise rolling summation that is done with the interior LET does this, but I cannot see a simpler approach.